# I'm not sure I can flash the firmware rom on Mac Pro 1,1

Tags: mac, mac-pro, efi, firmware

I'm trying to port coreboot to the Mac Pro 1,1 and I'm finding it difficult to locate any information on how to use the diag/lpc or other ports to flash firmware on the Mac Pro 1,1 or 2,1.

I am generally trying to get a 64 bit firmware working on this mac.

The Intel Xeon X5470 supports SSE 4.1 and I see no reason then that this Mac cannot run High Sierra or Big Sur.

My goal is to make a firmware for it that will allow this.

I found a Firmware Restoration CD image but I don't believe it will run if I totally brick the flash trying to flash SerialICE and I have a problem where I need to be able to flash it in the event of a complete brick, before attempting to debug and reverse engineer the boot sequence of the chipset, and build coreboot for it using a flash programming method, which is generally required for this to work.

I did manage to find out that the USB debug is on USB port 0 and requires a high speed USB 2 debug serial device, which is helpful for early debugging of the chipset and ram initialization, but nothing on the LPC bus or using SPI/JTAG to talk to the embedded controller, or how the firmware is originally flashed at the factory on this old mac.

I am generally trying to upgrade the firmware to be 64 bits, which is possible, hypothetically, as far as I can tell. The CPUs are both 64 bits as is the memory controller,and the chipset seems to have no documented limitation on this working in 64 bits.

Comment: Some Service Manuals for older Macs can be found [here](http://www.tim.id.au/blog/tims-laptop-service-manuals/#toc-apple).

Comment: Unfortunately there is nothing in the service manual about the debug/jtag or any kind of SPI/LPC flashing.

Comment: If this is better suited for an electronics site, please flag as needed for a cross site migration